# Crystal report login failure - prompting user/pass when database has none

Tags: visual-studio-2010, authentication, crystal-reports

My crystal reports viewer prompts me to login even though my database has no username and password.  When I leave userID and Password blank it still fails to log in.

Kindly please help me friends

Answer (score 2):

thank you aMazing but i found the solution

I read somewhere that if the source table does not be filled crystal report prompt to loging in , but when i was trying   to set filled table as datasource of report an error accoured saying crdb_adoplus.dll not find
it was for bad inistallation i think , however bellow link solved the problem

http://www.sourcehints.com/articles/how-to-use-crystal-report-2010-in-vs2010.html

Comment: It works. But the setup is okay. It is a bug in the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add a dataset to your report, there is a Checkbox that reads Integrated Security.
Leave your id and password blank and select that checkbox and try. Might solve your problem.